# WebView и получение токена

Tags: android, java, webview, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки! Наверное, у меня глупый вопрос, но все же.

Я пытаюсь в андроид-приложении прикрутить авторизацию Вконтакте с помощью WebView. Мне нужно, чтобы при запуске приложения запускалась активити с WebView, где пользоавтель мог ввести логин, пароль и после чего получить токен.

Я делаю так:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loginWebView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.clearCache(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

        String url = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=123&scope=65544"; 
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }   
}
```

В итоге открывается активити, на ней WebView отображает диалог авторизации вконтакте. А вот что делать дальше, я не знаю. ( Как получить этот токен из вебвью?

Comment: А их сдк? Удобное. WebViewClient - в нем работа с запросами.

Comment: Хотелось бы без сдк (ну или когда-нибудь потом), потому что уже очень многое написано без его использования, и прикручивать его только ради одной авторизации не хочется.

Answer (score 2):

[@JuniorTwo](/users/11955/juniortwo), тебе нужно для своего WebView установить [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html). У него есть метод-callback [onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)](http://bit.ly/1DxMPMt). Как видишь, вторым параметром придёт ссылка, в которой будет указан токен. А вот выдрать токен из строки - это уже твоя задача. Сам URL будет типа *http://REDIRECT_URI#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492*